# Access class after asynchronous loading file using promise () ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to ECMAScript am trying to load a file asynchronously and access the class but am not able to do so.

my `main.js` has basic class

```
console.log("=============in main script=================")

class test{

    constructor(auth_key,auth_secret){
        this.auth_key = auth_key;
        this.auth_secret = auth_secret;
        console.log("============In class test============");
    }

    init(){
        console.log("============In init function============"+this.auth_key);
    }
}
```

trying to access class in `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sttAsyncLoad(){
    console.log("===========loading script asynchronously============");
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var s;
        s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = "src/main.js";
        s.onload = resolve;
        s.onerror = reject;
        document.head.appendChild(s);
    });
}
sttAsyncLoad();

let sObj = new test("test","test11");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

output getting error `Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined`.

Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: See that all browsers do not support ES6 features at all. So you have to use a compiler like TypeScript or Babel.. You can check at [Caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is not going to wait until the promise is resolved. It will run

```
let sObj = new test("test","test11");
```

immediately, no matter whether the script is already loaded.

Instead, use the promise's `then()` to wait for it to resolve:

```
function sttAsyncLoad(){
    console.log("===========loading script asynchronously============");
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var s;
        s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = "src/main.js";
        s.onload = resolve;
        s.onerror = reject;
        document.head.appendChild(s);
    });
}
sttAsyncLoad().then(function() {
    let sObj = new test("test","test11");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for `sttAsyncLoad` to finish before calling `new test()`. Since you're using a promise, you could do this with something like

```
sttAsyncLoad().then(function() { let sObj = new test("test", "test11"); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.